How to make ADFS Access Control Policy with rule that checks multiple groups using `AND` logic?
Is there an ability to make ADFS Access Control Policy rule that works when user in group A and group B ?
I need to permit access to some application only for users in APPLICATION_USERS group.
I also have MFA for all users, but I have MFA_BYPASS group for some of them.
This means that I need two rules:
rule1:
   Permit users
   from APPLICATION_USERS group
   and require MFA
   except from MFA_BYPASS group
rule2:
   Permit users
   from APPLICATION_USERS group

How can I be sure that rule2 will not be applied for everyone who is in APPLICATION_USERS, but will be applied only to users who in APPLICATION_USERS and in MFA_BYPASS?
How I modify rule2 to form
rule2:
   Permit users
   from APPLICATION_USERS group
   AND from MFA_BYPASS group

to make member of MFA_BYPASS be explicitly checked (GUI does not allow this AND)?
